# What does small delta stand for in this equation for Digital Control Systems?

Tags: linear-transformations

What does the small delta sign stand for in this example describing linearization for Digital Control Systems?

[image: EXAMPLE PICTURE]

Comment: The explanation is there:  *"a small excursion about $\pi/4$"*. Similar to what matematicians call 'epsilon': a value as small as you like.

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit new to electronics, I have math as a major. So small delta is used to indicate "excursion" in this case? 

Furthermore, what does it mean when small delta is multiplied by "x"? Do we take 
the recursion with respect to f(x)?@Ripi2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\delta x$ describes the movement you choose to move away from $x_0 = \pi/4$ in either positive or negative direction. $x_0 = \pi/4$ is your point that you linearize the system around, and you can choose that point as you want but it's good to check if your point makes sence and that your system is stable around that point. You can analyse the stability of a system like this by using e.g. Lyapunov stability theorem.

If your system is stable, in control theory, you can move around this point without damaging your system, because the system is stable around that point after you linearize it by using Taylor expansion.

In the linearization process you choose

$$\delta x = x - x_0 = x - \pi/4$$

$x$ is usually said to be the state variable of the system. Your state depends on the movement you choose to make. It's good to look at state space representation and linearization books about control system theory to understand this better.
State space can be expressed on the form
$$
\dot x = Ax + Bu \\
y = Cx + Du
$$
but after you linearize the system you get
$$
\delta \dot x = A \delta x + B \delta u \\
\delta y = C \delta x + D \delta u
$$
which is the same as
$$
\delta \dot x = A (x-x_0) + B(u-u_0) \\
\delta y = C(x-x_0) + D(u-u_0)
$$
where $A$,$B$,$C$, and $D$ are state space matrices, $x$ is a state variable (or a vector), $u$ is a control variable (or a vector). $y$ is a measurement.

If you have $x=10$ in the nonlinear case, you have $\delta x = x-x_0 = 10-\pi/4$ in the linear case. So what you did is you took a nonlinear dynamical differential equation and turned it into a linear dynamical differential equation. When you have a linear equation, you can use linear control theory methods to design a feedback controller for that system.